# generating XML from config using python

Tags: python, xml

Please tell me how I can get out of *.conf [section name] and the value of the first parameter (after the name of the section) and on their basis to create a XML file using python? I have a very simple config file, but each section is more than one option. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the standard library you can find [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) which helps you read such files and [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) which helps you bould valid XML files (see sections about modifying and building).

Comment: Thank you. Now that I have turned out ugly, but it works)

Answer (score 0):

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET # on Python 3.3+ use xml.etree.ElementTree instead
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('sipusers.conf')    

Main = ET.Element("Main")
ET.SubElement(Main, "TCMIPPhoneDirectory", clearlight="true")
ET.SubElement(Main, "Title").text = "Phonelist"
ET.SubElement(Main, "Prompt").text = "Prompt"

for section in config.sections():
    Child = ET.SubElement(Main, "DirectoryEntry")
    ET.SubElement(Child, "Name").text = section
    ET.SubElement(Child, "Telephone").text = config.get(section,'username') 

xml = ET.ElementTree(Main)
xml.write("phonebook.xml")
```